# Trouble Making Spooles

Tags: makefile, command, global, linux-mint

I am trying to make Spooles 2.2-9 on Mint Maya linux distro and I get the following error.

```
aaron@atown ~/Downloads/spooles $ sudo make global
cd A2/src             ; make -f makeGlobalLib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/aaron/Downloads/spooles/A2/src'
makeGlobalLib:19: warning: overriding commands for target `.c.o'
../../Make.inc:90: warning: ignoring old commands for target `.c.o'
/usr/lang-4.0/bin/cc -c -O basics.c -o A2_basics.o
make[1]: /usr/lang-4.0/bin/cc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [basics.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/aaron/Downloads/spooles/A2/src'
make: *** [global] Error 2
```

I am new to linux so any help would be most useful.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing it from your software package manager?  I know that package is provided by Ubuntu and Debian, and Mint is a derivative so it should have it available for installation.  No need to build it yourself.

If you do want to compile it yourself, first note you should never build software as root (don't prefix the `make` command with `sudo`).  It's possible that if there's an `install` step you'll need to run that as root, but generally not the build.

Second it looks like by default this package is configured to build on OSX (I think `/usr/lang-4.0/bin/cc` is an OSX path... maybe?).  In any event, that's not where the compiler lives on Linux: try this to override the compiler:

```
make CC=gcc global
```

It's also possible that your system does not have a compiler installed.  If you get an error from the above then use your software package manager to install the `gcc` package.

Comment: Solved! Thank you sooo much. This has been plaguing me for days. I still had to use sudo or I got a permission denied error, but it is working now. I have no idea why an OSX path was the default for this Ubuntu package, but thank you for the work around.